# src image changer after click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have this image in my html page:

```
<img src="/images/deactivate.png" onclick="act_deact(this);"/>
```

and in my javascript code i have this:

```
function act_deact(image) {
    image.src = (image.src=="/images/activate.png" ) ? "/images/deactivate.png" : "/images/activate.png";
}
```

and when i click on the image that initially deactivated it activate but in the second click it doesn't desactivate !

is there any probleme with my code ?

from JS amateur :)

Comment: Well it works for absolute URLs: http://jsfiddle.net/4rNha/1/

Comment: @Antony : yes i have tried that with the server adress and it works. but i work in localhost and i dont want to make the complete url with host and port for just making it works !, is there an other solution to make it work with relatif url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself :p and i have tried @fardjad proposition that is looking for string in the url and make conditions

i share the solution :)

```
function act_deact(image) {
if(image.src.indexOf('deactivate') != -1)
   image.src="/images/activate.png";
else 
   image.src="/images/deactivate.png";
}
```

@hjpotter92: the solution with check condition on `image.alt` works to:

html:

```
<img alt="deactivate" src="/images/deactivate.png" onClick="act_deact(this);" />
```

the Js function :

```
function act_deact(image) { 
    if (image.alt=="activate") {
       image.src = "/images/deactivate.png";
       image.alt = "deactivate"                                          }
    else {  
       image.src = "/images/activate.png"; 
       image.alt = "activate"
    }
}
```

thanks for your responses :)

Answer (score 4):

This is because when you set it to(or it changes to) `/images/activate.png` on first click, the `src` attribute is no longer just `/images/activate.png` but it gets prefixed with the server-address.

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hGcqq/

Or on your own server, use a `console.log` or an `alert` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

[@hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92) already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16213111/303270) the reason it doesn't work.

One way to make it work is to check if **src** ends with `/images/activate.png`:

```
var activateURL = '/images/activate.png';
if (img.src.substring(img.src.length - activateURL.length) !== activateURL) {
    image.src = '/images/activate.png';
} else {
    image.src = '/images/deactivate.png';
}
```

Comment: yes good idea, i will try to find `activate` or `deactivate` in the url and make condition of returned result :)

Answer (score 0):

The image.src contains the canonical path, even if initialised with a relative path. You can either use the full path in the condition like

```
function act_deact(image) {
    image.src = (image.src=="FULL-PATH-OF-IMAGE" ) ? "/images/deactivate.png" : "images/activate.png";
}
```

(to get the full path one may use alert(image.src);)

or, if all your images have unique names

```
function act_deact(image) {
    image.src = image.src.match(/activate.png$/) ? "/images/deactivate.png" : "images/activate.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is brackets which should be like this:

```
image.src = (image.src=="/images/activate.png" ? "/images/deactivate.png" : "/images/activate.png")
```

Also try image.getAttribute("src") and image.setAttribute("src") instead of image.src.

Please try this code:

```
function act_deact(image) {
    image.setAttribute("src", (image.getAttribute("src")=="/images/activate.png" ? "/images/deactivate.png" : "/images/activate.png"))
}
```

Edit: other answers tell you about the issue of absolute and relative urls, so getAttribute will fix that issue. I do not recommend to use RegExp or substrings here.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with relative url you can simply save current url like this:

```
var newsrc = "/images/deactivate.png";
function act_deact(image) {
  if ( newsrc == "/images/deactivate.png" ) {
    image.src = "/images/activate.png";
    newsrc  = "/images/activate.png";
  }
  else {
    image.src = "/images/deactivate.png";
    newsrc  = "/images/deactivate.png";
  }
}
```

and then call it

```
<img src="/images/deactivate.png" onclick="act_deact(this);"/>
```

Comment: Why not just check based on `img.alt` attribute?

Comment: That would probably work too but the original question didn't have it so I removed that part of code from my answer. =)

Comment: Using `alt` imho, was better though.